# Getting the Actual name and path of server address

Tags: apache, http

I am trying to get actual server address by using HttpServletRequest.The problem is if i use the code like this

```
    String hostdonate = request.getScheme() + "://" +
    request.getHeader("host") + 
    request.getContextPath()+"/getDonationDetails"
```

It will return http://localhost:8084/Test/getDonationDetails.Here Test is the project name.This is fine for localhost that is in my computer.Now i want to deploy my application into server address 33.124.165.12.Now if i use the same code it is returning something like http://localhost:8080/getDonationDetails.Here getDonationDetails is the method that i want to execute after returning to the address.And it is redirecting to empty page with error "site not reachable".How to get the actual address of my server like 33.124.165.12/getDonationDetails or any correct name or path of server address.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this:

```
public String getInetAddress() {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = null;
        String address = null;
        try {
            e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            LOGGER.info("Error in : " + e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
            if ("eth0".equalsIgnoreCase(n.getName())) {
                Enumeration<InetAddress> ee = n.getInetAddresses();
                while (ee.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
                    address = i.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
```

This will return the private ip of your existing server.

Comment: How to append my method name to the address?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `getRequestURL()` of `HttpServletRequest`. It will return the protocol, server name, port number, and server path from which you should be able to retrieve the IP of your server.